# MustacheJS not rendering in IE8

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a dynamic template which I append on a `div` when the page loads, it is working on Chrome and some other browsers, however it doesnt work in IE8.

Any idea why it doesn't work in IE8 ?

Heres the code

```
var notificationDetails = {
    dangerMessage: "",
    seats: data.seatRemaining,
    class:"product-notification-danger"
};

var templates = '<div class="panel {{class}}"><button type="button" class="close" data-target="#product-notification" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true" style=" border: 4px solid #fff; border-radius: 50%; display: block; color: #FFFFFF; background-color: rgba(0,0,0.6); font-size: 25; width: 32px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 5px; ">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span> </button> <div class="notication"> <div class="notification-section"><img src="/media/13583871/ms-device.png" width="126" class="mCS_img_loaded"></div><div class="notification-section"><div class="panel-heading"> <span class="product-notification-title">Protect <span id="remaining-seats">{{seats}}</span> more devices.</span></div><div class="panel-body"> <p>{{dangerMessage}}</p><p><a href="#" style="color:#fff; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 700;">Learn More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right">&nbsp;</span></a></p></div></div></div></div>'

$('#product-notification').append(Mustache.to_html(templates, notificationDetails));
```

Comment: What does your web console say? (press F12)

Comment: It works on any browser except IE8

Answer (score 2):

It just let the script run in my `IE8`.

[image]

I'd say it's simply not supported (anymore). And I also think that you don't need to support IE8. Or is there any reason to do so?